# Analyse Text window in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am facing a strange problem while using TeXstudio.
I have a code which goes like this:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \section*{A Short summary- no problem in analyse text}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Now, I am analysing the text (Tools---> Analyse Text). This will open-up the window as shown here:
[image: Picture for short section heading]

Kindly note the partition between as indicated in red lines.
Now I have another code which goes like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \section*{A lengthy summary of section highlighting the problem in analyse text}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

If I am analysing the text for this code, note the window partition here:[image: Picture for long section heading]

The only difference between both the set of code is that second one have longer section name, whereas first one does not. If I am giving bigger section names, this spacing becomes highly asymmetric. I cannot drag the line in between the red lines and hence it is difficult to see the areas such as Word/Phrase, Count and Count Relative. What is happening here?

Software Version:TeXstudio 2.12.22 (git 2.12.22)

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language

Comment: Section titles appear in the drop-dow menu of option "Sources", which I guess triggers the different windows partitions. Perhaps you can widen the window by hovering cursor at the right border of window, and dragging? If you feel a necessary to report to texstudio, open an issue in https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues.

Comment: Thanks 4 the suggestion. I tried hovering cursor as you have mentioned. But still problem persist. Are you also experiencing the same problem for the given code? If yes, i will try to report it.

Comment: On my side, longer section title do makes the right column narrower, but in each case widening the "Text Analysis" window always solely widen the right column, hence solves the problem. Perhaps you can try a newer [texstudio 3.0.0rc3](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/tag/3.0.0rc3). It the problem remains, just open an issue there.